# Thread only working on second run

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a Singleton in an Android App (which works just fine) in one of the functions I need to set data in a class variable in another thread but the data only sets if I run the function twice.

onCreate:

```
Thread thread;
Runnable runnables;
String recvData;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();  
    singleInstance = this;
    recvData = "one";
    Log.v("oncreate", "singleton");
}
```

threaded_data_set:

```
public String threaded_set_data() {
    runnables = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recvData = "two";
            return;
        }
    };
    thread = new Thread(runnables);
    thread.start()
    Log.v("Data", recvData);
    return recvData;
}
```

on the first run it logs `("Data", "one")` and only on the second one it changes to `("Data", "two")`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong. That is how a thread works. It completes calling the start method and returns the value by tht tym the runnable does its work. Try using a handler instead

Answer (score 2):

The default values of `recvData` is:

```
recvData = "one";
```

nothing is wrong here, the

```
Log.v("Data", recvData);
```

just printed out before your thread prints out the second log message.

Comment: Alright I understand that now but this function is meant to return the value for use in other activities, how should I return it so the data is already modified since on the first run it also returns the default value..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an android developer, I just tried to explain why your program behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming the thread has finished as soon as you get to the logging statement.

Try logging the value in the thread as you set it as well, you'll see that code happens *after* your first logging call.

It is working right but you're expecting the thread to finish before your method moves on is all :)

Answer (score 0):

Not much is going wrong here, you just aren't using the new assignment value for `recvData`

```
public String threaded_set_data()
{
    runnables = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
                        recvData = "two";
                        Log.v("Data", recvData);
                        //return; <-- not really needed
                    }
    };
    thread = new Thread(runnables);
    thread.start()
    Log.v("Data", recvData);
    return recvData;
}
```

Comment: no need to use new for recData, it's a String, the assignment `recvData = "one";` is totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

At the first run of the thread, the latter is running in it's own thread which means that you're already returning recvData before the runnable finishes running since it's running in parallel. What you would want to do is use an AsyncTask instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're seem to missing the nuances of how threads work. I think you are assuming that your threads runs and returns before your log statement, however you can't safely assume that.

Instead, try using a handler like the comment in your question. A [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is designed exactly for this type of thing.  [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com) (a fantastic resource btw) does a much better job of e[xplaining it so I will direct you there.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: I've changed the Thread to AsyncTask but returning still happens before the thread finishes so I thought that having a flag set OnPostExecute to true and only return when it's true, is this a right way of handling that or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try using a handler?